# Using ngx-print, the background is always print in white

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Actualy i'm using [ngx-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print) npm library to print my `div` , it works fine , the only problem is that it's not displaying the background color as in the real one:

[image]

**My HTML Code :**

```
<div class="hover-div">
    <button mat-button class="title-div" printSectionId="card-container" 
         printTitle="professionalcard" [useExistingCss]="true" ngxPrint>
            <div fxLayout="row">
                <mat-icon class="preview-icon">print</mat-icon>
                <div>print</div>
            </div>
     </button>
</div>
```

has anyone encountered this problem before ? , if yes what is the solution , Thanks.

**Note:** i tried also to print the `div` without using the library , using `window.print()` , and i have always the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact` to print your background in real colors

Answer (score 2):

The `-webkit-print-color-adjust` property is a non-standard extension that can be used to force the printing of images and colors used in the background for WebKit-based browsers.

By default , it is initialized to `economy` thats why the background is not printing in the real colors , to fix this , we will have to change its value to : `exact` , this solved the problem for google chrom.

The alternate of this CSS in firefox and IE is : `color-adjust: exact | economy;`.

Now it is working perfectly !